# Onclick action from html to firefox add-on

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I have a function in the add-on and I have an image in the page. How can I call that function from the add-on when the user click on the image?

```
<img src='something' onclick="thisfunction();"> //what is need to call thisfuntion function in the add-on?
//in the add-on:
function thisfunction(){ .... }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that HTML code you inject into the web page? Then you should attach an event listener:

```
img.addEventListener("click", thisfunction, false);
```

Comment: can you help more? how its work? <img src='something' onclick="thisfunction(text/number);"> function thisfunction(variable){ here do the things } how it seens in the firefox addon? (I started now only this so I don't know a lot of thing.... sry) oh and the imgs are added to html when the page loaded

Comment: It's impossible to use onclick event like that, I need for an evenetListener for it. Also, I need an id or something to specify (only) that image in the DOM content at the web page.